# Specifying shapefiles for clusters and subclusters using Folium's MarkerCluster

Tags: leaflet, folium

For example, I'd like to zoom from country, to states, to counties.

I don't see this option in [the docs](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html):

`class folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(locations=None, popups=None, icons=None, name=None, overlay=True, control=True, show=True, icon_create_function=None, options=None, **kwargs)`

But the Marker Cluster object does highlight contours when hovering over a cluster icon:

[image: Folium Marker Cluster]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Folium version of MarkerCluster plugin, but JS version by default zooms to bounds of a cluster when you click on it. Option is called `zoomToBoundsOnClick` and is true by default. Try specifying this option in `Options` parameter.

Comment: Yes, but those bounds seem to be set under the hood by some algorithm.

Comment: Yes, algorithm is very simple: at any given zoom cluster together markers that are closer in pixels than value set by `maxClusterRadius` option (default value 80). There is no option to change this algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.